# Substitute a function with an expression in Z3

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I'm working with the [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) Python API, and I'd like to take an expression, and substitute it for a declared function. That is, I'd like to do something like the following:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = Ints('x y')

# In practice, this could be a dynamically
# generated expression
expr = x + y * 2

f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort())

# Not sure how to implement this
function_substitute(f(x, y) == f(y, x) + f(4,0), (f, [x,y], expr))
# Results in x + y * 2 == y + x * 2 + 4
```

Originally, I thought I wanted a function that wraps `expr` (which Levent provided a great answer for), but having thought about it, this isn't particularly helpful from a substitutional approach and definitely feels a bit hacky.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual thing to do, but here's one solution:

```py
from z3 import *

def functionFromExpr(args, expr):
    return lambda *fargs: substitute(expr, zip (args, fargs))

x, y = Ints ('x y')
expr = x + y

f = functionFromExpr([x, y], expr)

print (f (x, y))
print (f (x, IntVal(4)))
print (f (IntVal(3), IntVal(4)))
```

This prints:

```
x + y
x + 4
3 + 4
```

Note that you need to pass expressions explicitly, by appropriately converting them yourself at the call site. If you want to avoid that, you can instead do the following:

```
def mkExpr(a):
    if is_expr(a):
        return a
    elif isinstance(a, int):
        return IntVal(a)
    elif isinstance(a, float):
        return FPVal(a)
    else:
        raise Exception("Don't know how to convert: %s"  % a.__repr__())

def functionFromExpr(args, expr):
    return lambda *fargs: substitute(expr, zip (args, [mkExpr(e) for  e in fargs]))

x, y = Ints ('x y')
expr = x + y

f = functionFromExpr([x, y], expr)

print (f (x, y))
print (f (x, 4))
print (f (3, 4))
```

Obviously, you'll have to modify `mkExpr` appropriately to handle all sorts of constants you might be passing.

Comment: Thank you! Why is this an unusual thing to do? I would have thought that generating expressions, and wanting to substitute them into larger expressions is a relatively common thing to want to do?

Comment: As I just want to replace instances of f(x,y) with expressions like the above, am I better off writing `expr = z3.Lambda([x y], x + y) ` and finding some method for mapping the `f` to `expr`?

Comment: Why not just `def f (x, y): return x+y`? This'll work for all the examples you posted except for `f(3, 4)`, which will return `7` instead of `3 + 4`; and I'm not sure why you'd want to distinguish the two.

Comment: So I'd like to be able to do that for an arbitrary, dynamically generated expression `expr`. Perhaps my question was poorly phrased, but I'd like to be able to take a dynamically generated expression, `expr`, which has some free (arbitrary number of, but defined previously) variables and replace `f(x,y)` with `expr(x,y)`. `expr` could be `x+y` or it could be `x * y + x**2` or any other z3 expression. I've been playing around with it, but `substitute` isn't quite as flexible as I'd like it to be.